# Ideas how to build a screen with 100 Views added programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now I'm stuck how to manage to build a specific Activity in my app. I've added an image so I can explain my problem:

[image: The layout of this Activity]

So first of all: all the content will be loaded from an API. "Static text" in my image means that I can define these parts in my activity.xml and don't have to do that in my Activity.java because these parts will be always the same for the screen (meaning the size of the elements, the content will be loaded from my API).
The green box should be horizontal scrollable or not depending how many boxes have to be shown here (1 to 3 possible).
The blue box will be generated in my Activity (in the end it should look like a table) and I want to define the layout of a single row in a separate xml (e.g. table_row.xml) so I could change it easily. This table can have up to 100 rows depending on how many are returned by the API.

So my problem right now is: Obviously this whole layout has to be scrollable so my first idea was to use ScrollView and a LinearLayout as child. But I read here on stackoverflow that the performance will be really poor if you use LinearLayout and add Views to it. So everyone recommended using a ListView for this part (meaning the blue box for my Activity). But that would mean only my blue box will be scrollable as you should not use a ListView in a ScrollView.

So my question is: How can I make this whole screen scrollable with a table dynamic in size without losing performance?

Comment: Tbh: When I read `screen with 100 Views` I stopped reading...

Comment: 100vieews. think of redesigning.

Comment: I would seriously consider re-designing the way the application works, 100 views would be a ridiculous amount of views to display in a single activity. Perhaps you should look into paging? - Also depending on what the views are you may have other problems when adding them to a listview as focus is a problem when adding things like textviews etc to a listview (they tend to fight for focus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the first three layouts as `ListView` **Header** and make your blue box layout as the list view. By this you'll be able to scroll the complete `View` i.e. Blue Box, however the first three layouts will be static and won't scroll.